# How to install Solr 1.4 with plug-ins (I've error loading class 'solr.FastLRUCache')?

Tags: tomcat, installation, solr

I installed Tomcat, and got SOLR version 1.3 working no problem by copying the "conf" directory from the "example" directory in the 1.3 release files.

Now I've just downloaded the SOLR 1.4 release, but can't get it to work.

I've noticed the new solrconfig.xml file in the 1.4 release "example" directory has some new settings which reference items in "lib" and "distr" folder.

Also, the example directory in the 1.4 release doesn't have any "lib" folders.

Not being a JAVA/Tomcat guy, I'm totally confused as to getting everything working. I'm not sure where to put the "lib", "distr" folders from the 1.4 release into my solr directory.

There's loads of different folders, and .jar files, in the 1.4 release, and I'm not sure what to do with them??

### Ideally i'd like all the reference plug-ins in the default solrconfig.xml to work, and in particular I need that the **RequestExtractiongHandler** works.

can anyone help?

cheers

### UPDATE:

The specific error I keep getting is when I copy the solrconfig.xml from the 1.4 release exmaple folder, is this:

> HTTP Status 500 - Severe errors in solr configuration (...) Error loading class 'solr.FastLRUCache'

I don't think the error is specific to that class, I think it's a general issue with me not knowing where to put the necessary .jar files... and how to reference them

Comment: Hey there. Just had a look inside my solrconfig.. Which was the default one from the 1.4 version.. I don't have any reference to the above Handler.. Only <requestHandler name="/update/extract" class="org.apache.solr.handler.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler" startup="lazy"> Have you deffo installed the 1.4 version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you know which JAR has the file you need?  If so, after the solr.war file has been expanded under Tomcat, you should be able to drop the JAR(s) into `$CATALINA_HOME/solr/WEB-INF/lib` (assuming you installed solr into Tomcat using the solr.war included in the distribution; if not, you should do that first).

Comment: thanks danben, I'm gonna check this out later today and see if it works. cheers

Comment: hi, sorry danben, been super busy.. checking it now

Comment: dude, you're literally a genius! I love the open source philosophy, but why are the tutorials so half arsed!

Comment: I got the vanilla version working. I'm now gonna try using the extractionhandler and set it up with my original multi-core setup. you cool to just check up on this question in the next week or so? I might run into problems

Comment: Also, if I don't respond you can e-mail me at gmail

Answer (score 4):

I've created a step by step [blog post](http://craftyfella.blogspot.com/2009/12/installing-solr-14-on-windows-xp-step.html) for this. Complete with screen shots. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey craftyfella, does your installation guide include the plugins working including the RequestExtractiongHandler? cheers!

Comment: Try now... let me know if it helps.. or any spelling/confusing bits and i'll edit.

Comment: Nope.. Just the standard 1.4 out of the box version.

Comment: ahhh... see that's the issue, i can't get the plug-ins working. Really, I just need the RequestExtractiongHandler working

Comment: Ok i'll take a look tomorrow.. I thought you wanted 1.4 working on windows.

Comment: yeah, with plug-ins... it's cool, let me know if you have any success!

Comment: This is link-only answer and it should be expanded.

Answer (score 2):

For quickly trying out SOLR I found [LucidWorks at Lucidimagination](http://www.lucidimagination.com) to be amazing.  A single installer that will install and configure all the bits and pieces for you.

Comment: These guys seems to want $100,000?  Are they opensource?  Is that just for support, or do you need to pay it just to use it?

Comment: As far as I know you can use it, but if you want support you have to pay for that.  However we have been going along just fine.  I posted it because it was so quick and easy to get going.  If you are getting into SOLR you would probably do a lot of the things yourself all ready.